# Evaluating function in a grid, 18 dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, minimization

I would like to evaluate how a model of 18 parameters (0 to 1) would fit some experimental data. Minimization is also constrained by very complicated relations linking the 18 parameters. Eventually, I can build a function boundary(f11, f12, ...) of 18 variables of known value, that I can evaluate in each point in order to weed out what combinations of these 18 parameters are "good", and later evaluate the model function on those. For a given set of (f11, f12, ...) parameters, evaluating the "boundary" function is 500x faster than the "model" function.

With a ridiculously rough grid, I still end up with around 10^6 points. Evaluating the boundary function on 10^4 points takes about 20" using a Python 2 code, so scaling up to any useful grid (on the order of 10^12 points or more) is out of the question. I also know Python is notoriously slow for number crunching.

Questions:

1. Is there any chance a different approach (Fortran) could be 1000x faster?
2. Assuming a very fast algorithm exists, is there any chance to work with a reasonable number of points (say, 10^12), evaluating one by one so memory/storage isn't overloaded?

Example code follows (real code is some 1000 lines long due to very long definition of boundary function). Thanks!

```py
# python2 example code with 3 parameters
# real code has 18 parameters

import numpy as np

def boundary(arr):
    f11,f12,f13 = arr
    return f11*f12+f11*f12*f13-(1-f12)*f13

N = 3
threshold = 0.1

sample_f11 = np.linspace(0,1,N)
sample_f12 = np.linspace(0,1,N)
sample_f13 = np.linspace(0,1,N)

parameters = [(f11, f12, f13) for f11 in sample_f11 for f12 in sample_f12\
for f13 in sample_f13]

good_points = [i for i in parameters if boundary(i) < threshold]

#the real boundary function looks like this:
#def boundary(arr):    
#    f11,f12,f24,f25,f37,f38,f41,f42,f54,f55,f67,f68,f71,f72,f84,f85, \
#    f97,f98 = arr
#    return (2*-((f54*f71*f97*(f97-f68*f97+f67*f98)* \
#    (f71*(-(-(1-f55)*f84-f54*f85)*f97-(-(1-f55)* \
#    f84-f54*f85)*(-f38*f97+f37*f98)+(1-f55-(1-f55)* \
#    f84-f54*f85)*(f97-f68*f97+f67*f98)+f42*((-(1-f55)*f84-f54*f85)*f97+ \
#    [... 700 more lines]
```

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour].

Comment: BTW, you cannot even declare an array with 18 dimensions in standard Fortran, only 14. It is insane.

Comment: "is there any chance to work with a reasonable number of points, evaluating one by one so memory/storage isn't overloaded?" It's not is there any chance, you will HAVE to structure your code to deal with a manageable subset at a time to have any hope of doing this whatsoever. As for 1000 times or more faster, probably a compiled language on a reasonable size cluster will do it, especially if the points can be evaluated independently, but without much more detail can't say for certain. At first glance this a far from trivial calculation.

Comment: I thought a nested for loop iterating over each parameter and then evaluating the function just for one single (f11,f12,...) point of the grid could do the trick without defining an N-dimensional array. I understand this python2 code cannot scale to 18 dimensions. Thx for your suggestions.

Comment: `numpy` can handle up to 32 dimensions, and for whole array, numeric operations is respectfully fast.  Much of it is written `c`.  But `10**18` requires quite a bit of memory!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you attempting to do? Integration, lookup table, differentiation, ...? Is it not possible to find a mapping functions that translates a single index into 18 valid ones. If all points would be valid, that mapping function in 3D would be `i%N`, `(i/N)%N`, `(i/N)/N`